# Mongoose pull ObjectId from array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to do a pretty simple operation, pull an item from an array with Mongoose on a Mongo database like so:

```
User.update({ _id: fromUserId }, { $pull: { linkedUsers: [idToDelete] } });
```

`fromUserId` & `idToDelete` are both Objects Ids.

The schema for Users goes like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  groups: [],
  linkedUsers: [],
  name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } }
});
```

`linkedUsers` is an array that only receives Ids of other users.

I've tried this as well:

```
User.findOne({ _id: fromUserId }, function(err, user) {
  user.linkedUsers.pull(idToDelete);
  user.save();
});
```

But with no luck.

The second option seem to almost work when i console the lenghts of the array at different positions but after calling `save` and checking, the length is still at 36:

```
 User.findOne({ _id: fromUserId }, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user.linkedUsers.length); // returns 36
    user.linkedUsers.pull(idToDelete);
    console.log(user.linkedUsers.length); // returns 35
    user.save();
  });
```

So it looks like i'm close but still, no luck. Both Ids are sent via the frontend side of the app.
I'm running those versions:

```
"mongodb": "^2.2.29",
"mongoose": "^5.0.7",
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `User.findOneAndUpdate(fromUserId, { "$pull": { "linkedUsers": idToDelete } }, { "new": true }, callback);`?

Comment: Just did and no luck as well. Weird thing, in the second argument of the callback, i got a user that has nothing to do with the two Ids used as arguments.

Comment: Just realised my mistake, meant the other method `User.findByIdAndUpdate(fromUserId, { "$pull": { "linkedUsers": idToDelete } }, { "new": true }, callback);` or `User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: fromUserId }, { "$pull": { "linkedUsers": idToDelete } }, { "new": true }, callback);` ?

Comment: Tried both and the callback gives me back the right user this time. But i can see that the id does not get pulled from the array. 
Looks like i'm not the only one struggling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625633/nodejs-mongoose-mongodb-pull-from-array-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Really looks like there's something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explicitly define the types in your schema definition i.e. `groups: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }], linkedUsers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]`?

Comment: That's was it! I've updated my model and used `User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: fromUserId },
      { $pullAll: { linkedUsers: [idToDelete] } },
      { new: true },
      function(err, data) {}
    );` Could you set your comment as answer so i can accept it? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just being curious. Have you tried casting string to objectid like `User.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: fromUserId }, { $pullAll: { linkedUsers: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idToDelete)] } }, { new: true }, function(err, data) {} );` with your old schema ?

Comment: @Veeram just did out of curiosity too and yes it worked. Gonna keep the other way though, cleaner. But good to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the types in your schema definition i.e.

```
groups: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }], 
linkedUsers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

and then use either

```
User.findOneAndUpdate( 
    { _id: fromUserId }, 
    { $pullAll: { linkedUsers: [idToDelete] } }, 
    { new: true }, 
    function(err, data) {} 
);
```

or

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(fromUserId, 
    { $pullAll: { linkedUsers: [idToDelete] } }, 
    { new: true }, 
    function(err, data) {} 
);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to delete an object from an array, using the default _id from mongo, but my query was wrong:

```
const update = { $pull: { cities: cityId }};
```

It should be:

```
const update = { $pull: { cities: {_id: cityId} }};
```