# Why pull is not removing elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to remove elements from the array, seem like it's not working, here is the model
**1. Question Model**

```
   {

    reviews: [{ type: ObjectID, ref: 'Review' }]

   }
```

**2. Review Model**

```
    {
      description: {
      type: String
    },
      userId: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
   }
```

**And here is my service for the Quuestion.js**

```
export const deleteReview = async ({ reviewId, id }, user) => {
  try {
    const result = await Question.updateOne(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $pull: { reviews: { _id: reviewId, userId: user._id } }
      }
    ).exec();
    if (result.nModified === 0) {
      throw new APIError({ message: msg('Unauthorized'), status: 401 });
    }
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**Routes file**

```
  router.delete('/questions/:id/reviews/:reviewId', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const {
        params,
        user
      } = req;
      const data = await deleteReview( params,
        user);
      return res.status(200).json({ data });
    } catch (err) {
      error(res, err);
    }
  });
```

I was trying to remove the elements but it's not removing at all, I have no idea where I did a mistake.

Comment: try to follow this question's top answer, which seems close to what you are doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988019/mongoose-pull-objectid-from-array

Comment: I was following the same, seems the $pull operator removes elements by specifying a query only,  @kibe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution I got, the $pull is not working so  applied the $pullAll**

```
export const deleteReview = async ({ reviewId, id }, user) => {
  try {
    const result = await Question.updateOne(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $pullAll: { reviews: [{ _id: reviewId, userId: user._id }] }
      }
    ).exec();
    if (result.nModified === 0) {
      throw new APIError({ message: msg('Unauthorized'), status: 401 });
    }
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```